# embedd youtube video without share option

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, youtube, embedding

I have an iPhone app where I am playing youtube videos.

I have tableview where I am listing all videos.

I am using below code to play youtube vide.

```
<html><style>iframe {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}</style>
    <body>
        <iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/rxSwgvMg-H4?rel=0&html5=1' width='100' height='75' frameborder='0' >
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

All is working fine.

However client is insisting to remove share and text of video that are coming on the top.

[image]

Any idea how can I get this done?

Comment: this link help you http://www.squidoo.com/adding-a-play-image-on-top-of-an-embedded-youtube-video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/rxSwgvMg-H4?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&fs=0' width='300' height='175' frameborder='0' >
</iframe>
```

working link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bh4ac/

Remove Red color from play button:

```
<center><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HAR49CWiEjY?modestbranding=1&amp;title=&amp;autoplay=0&amp;re l=0&amp;controls=0" type=”application/x-shockwave-flash” frameborder="0" width="600" height="400"></iframe></center>
```

Comment: after testing I will approve... Dont worry, you will get reputation

Comment: any idea how can I remove the red play button?

Comment: you want to custom play button adding on video frame

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore!